# Array Struct change size from with in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, resize

My problem is that i can't change the size of my array struct from inside a function but i can from `int main()`

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    InfoFriendBook *IFB = new InfoFriendBook [TableSize];
    for ( int i=0; i < TableSize; i++ )
    {
        IFB[i] = NEWBOOK();                          /// Gives a name for fast debuging
        IFB[i].Last_Talked = Rand ( TableSize , 0 ); /// Gives a nr 0-10 for fast debuging
    }

    cout << " ";  /// have no need right now

    while ( ChooseMenu !=0 )
    {
        HeadMenu ( IFB , &TableSize );

        //IFB = ResizeArray ( IFB , &TableSize);
        //IFB = DeleteArrayMem( IFB , &TableSize );
    }

    delete []IFB;
}
```

my main looks like this where i have ResizeArray = Bigger and DeleteArrayMem = Smaller.

and if i use them from inside a function my program just crash if i try to see the list or try to resize it again.

my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


struct InfoFriendBook
{
    string Name;
    int Last_Talked;
    bool Active;
};

InfoFriendBook NEWBOOK ()
{
    InfoFriendBook NEW;
    NEW.Name = "NULL";
    NEW.Active = true;
    return NEW;
}

int *P_IFB = NULL;
int TableSize= 10, ChooseMenu=1 ;

void HeadMenu ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size );
void EditMenu ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size );
int Rand ( int high , int low );
void sort ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size );
int Find_Smallest_Nr ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size , int *Index );
void swap ( InfoFriendBook *IFBF , int Index , int Index2 , int *size );

InfoFriendBook *ResizeArray ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size );
InfoFriendBook *DeleteArrayMem ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size );

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    InfoFriendBook *IFB = new InfoFriendBook [TableSize];
    for ( int i=0; i < TableSize; i++ )
    {
        IFB[i] = NEWBOOK();                          /// Gives a name for fast debuging
        IFB[i].Last_Talked = Rand ( TableSize , 0 ); /// Gives a nr 0-10 for fast debuging
    }
    cout << " ";  /// have no need right now

    while ( ChooseMenu !=0 )
    {
        HeadMenu ( IFB , &TableSize );

        //IFB = ResizeArray ( IFB , &TableSize);
        //IFB = DeleteArrayMem( IFB , &TableSize );
    }
    delete []IFB;
}

void HeadMenu( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size )
{
    int Ranklist=1;
    cout << "\nFriends list\nSelect a menu\n1. For Print list.\n2. Sort list after how long it have been since last talk";
    cout << "\n3. Edit List\n";
    cin >> ChooseMenu;
    cin.ignore();
    switch ( ChooseMenu )
    {
    case 1: /// Print
        for ( int i=0; i < *size; i++ ) // Debug Print
        {
            if ( IFB[i].Active == true )
            {cout << endl << Ranklist << ". " << IFB[i].Name << "|" << IFB[i].Last_Talked;}
            else {break;}
        Ranklist++;
        } cout << endl << "Table Size: " << *size << "\nBookSize: "  << endl;
        break;

    case 2: /// Sort
        sort ( IFB , size ); // sorting
        break;

    case 3: /// Edit List
        EditMenu( IFB , size );
        break;
    }
}

void EditMenu ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size )
{
    int Ranklist=1;
    int Select, Nr, nr;
    cout << "\nEdit Menu\n1. Edit People\n2. Add People\n3. Delete People\n";
    cin >> ChooseMenu;
    cin.ignore();
    switch (ChooseMenu)
    {
    case 1: ///Edit Profile
        for ( int i=0; i < *size; i++ )
        {
            if ( IFB[i].Active == true )
                {cout << endl << Ranklist << ". " << IFB[i].Name << "|" << IFB[i].Last_Talked;}
            Ranklist++;
        }
        cout << "\nChoose a person to edit: ";
        cin >> Select;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nEdit Name 1. or Last time talk 2. ";
        cin >> ChooseMenu;
        cin.ignore();
        switch (ChooseMenu)
        {
            case 1:
                getline(cin, IFB[Select-1].Name);
                break;

            case 2:
                cin >> Nr;
                cin.ignore();
                while ( nr != 0 )
                {
                    nr = Nr;
                    nr = nr - Nr;
                    if( nr != 0)
                    {
                        cout << "You have try to place a negative nr. try again";
                        cin >> Nr;
                        cin.ignore();
                    }
                }
                IFB[Select-1].Last_Talked = Nr;
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 2: /// Add new profile
        Nr=0;
        IFB = ResizeArray ( IFB , size); // Grow struct array
        while ( IFB[Nr].Active == true )
        {
            Nr++;
        }
        IFB[Nr] = NEWBOOK();
        cout << "\nAdd new friend to list\nEnter name: ";
        getline(cin,IFB[Nr].Name);
        cout << "\nEnter Last time talk: ";
        cin >> IFB[Nr].Last_Talked;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nSorting started";
        sort( IFB , size );
        break;

    case 3: /// Delete Profile
        cout << "\nDelete one from list\n";
        Ranklist=1;
        for ( int i=0; i < *size; i++ )
        {
            if ( IFB[i].Active == true )
                {cout << endl << Ranklist << ". " << IFB[i].Name << "|" << IFB[i].Last_Talked;}
            Ranklist++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cin >> nr;
        cin.ignore();
        swap( IFB , (nr-1) , (*size-1) , size);
        cout << "\nSorting started";
        sort( IFB , size );
        IFB = DeleteArrayMem( IFB , size ); // Delete array Element []
        break;
    }
}


int Rand( int high , int low ) // Gives Random nr. out to how long it have been sins last time
{
    return rand() % ( high - low+ 1 ) + low;
}

void sort ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size  ) // find and place nr in order
{
    for ( int x=0; x < *size; x++ )
    {
        int Index = Find_Smallest_Nr( IFB , size , &x );
        swap ( IFB , x , Index , size );
    }
}

int Find_Smallest_Nr ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size , int *Index ) // find the smallest nr and returns it
{
    int SmallIndex = *Index;
    for ( int i= *Index+1 ; i < *size; i++ )
    {
        if ( IFB[i].Last_Talked < IFB[SmallIndex].Last_Talked )
        {
            SmallIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return SmallIndex;
}


void swap ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int Index , int Index2, int *size ) // place the smallest nr frist
{
    InfoFriendBook *Swap_IFB = new InfoFriendBook [*size]; // new swap take and swap element in a struct
    Swap_IFB[Index] = IFB[Index];
    IFB[Index] = IFB[Index2];
    IFB[Index2] = Swap_IFB[Index];
    delete [] Swap_IFB;
}

InfoFriendBook *ResizeArray ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size ) // Resize struct array
{
    InfoFriendBook *NEW_IFB = new InfoFriendBook [*size+1];
    for ( int x=0; x < *size; x++ )
    {
        NEW_IFB[x] = IFB[x];
    }
    delete []IFB;
    *size += 1;
    return NEW_IFB;
}

InfoFriendBook *DeleteArrayMem ( InfoFriendBook *IFB , int *size )
{
    InfoFriendBook *NEW_IFB = new InfoFriendBook [*size+1];
    NEW_IFB = new InfoFriendBook [*size-1];
    for ( int x=0; x< *size-1; x++ )
    {
        NEW_IFB[x] = IFB[x];
    }
    delete []IFB;
    *size -= 1;
    return NEW_IFB;
}
```

Comment: Dump the address of your pointer :), you pass your pointer by copy, so when you get back to the main function the pointer and the array have their original value. `( InfoFriendBook **IFB , int *size )`

Comment: Reduce your problems:  use `std::vector`.

Comment: This is a significant problem in `case 2:` of your nested switch: `while ( nr != 0 )`. You never initialize `nr` before that eval. By the looks of the code, this: `nr = Nr;` shouldn't be in the loop, and should be before the aforementioned `while`. The logic for that loop seems pointless regardless, as its "detection" of a negative `nr` is broken anyway.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. i have edit my headmenu and editmenu with `(InfoFriendBook **IFB , int int *size)` and my array struct grow and delete function now work. but i get and err on `fejl: request for member 'Name' in '*(IFB + ((((unsigned int)Select) + 0xffffffffffffffffu) * 4u))', which is of non-class type 'InfoFriendBook*'|` and it is on all that looks like `getline(cin, IFB[Select-1].Name);` what have i miss can some one point it out for me thx